# force close my app because shared preferenece

Tags: java, android

my application is still crashing I don't know

I think its because the shared preference

in A activity I load the shared preference that was saved in the B activity

and the application its forced close when its first launched

here is my A activity:

```
public class DawaaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button add;
SharedPreferences emportPref = this.getSharedPreferences("dawaaData",MODE_PRIVATE);;
String meDawaa = emportPref.getString("subject", "no data yet");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(DawaaActivity.this, meDawaa , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    initialaiz();
}

private void initialaiz() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent data = new Intent(DawaaActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
    startActivity(data);
}
```

}

this is my B Activity:

```
public class SettingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText et;
EditText et1;
Spinner list;
TimePicker startTime;
Button save;
Button cancel;
private SharedPreferences exportPref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    initialaiz();
}
private void initialaiz() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    list = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    startTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.save:
        save();
        Intent transferData = new Intent(SettingActivity.this,DawaaActivity.class);
        startActivity(transferData);
        break;
    case R.id.cancel:
        finish();
        break;
    }
}
public void save() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    exportPref = getSharedPreferences("dawaaData",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = exportPref.edit();
    editor.putString("subject", et.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("dosesC", et1.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("doses", list.getSelectedItem().toString());
    editor.putInt("hour", startTime.getCurrentHour());
    editor.putInt("minute", startTime.getCurrentMinute());
    editor.putInt("exists", 1);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"data has been saved" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

could you help me??

Comment: Post your dalvik log or else we can't help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
SharedPreferences emportPref = this.getSharedPreferences("dawaaData",MODE_PRIVATE);;
String meDawaa = emportPref.getString("subject", "no data yet");
```

To:

```
SharedPreferences emportPref;
String meDawaa;
```

And add the following to your onCreate() :

```
emportPref = this.getSharedPreferences("dawaaData",MODE_PRIVATE);
meDawaa = emportPref.getString("subject", "no data yet");
```

You were getting an error because you were trying to use the Activity context before it had been created in onCreate().